# Sums of Parts Python 3

Tags: python, performance

Let us consider this example (array written in general format):

`ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]`

Its following parts:

```
ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
ls = [1, 3, 6, 10]
ls = [3, 6, 10]
ls = [6, 10]
ls = [10]
ls = []
```

The corresponding sums are (put together in a list): [20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]

The function parts_sums (or its variants in other languages) will take as parameter a list ls and return a list of the sums of its parts as defined above.

I have tried like this but is not executed in given Execution Time.**How can I speed up this code:**

```
def parts_sums(ls):
    sums=[]
    if len(ls)==0:
        return[0]
    else:
        while len(ls)!=0:
            sums.append(sum(ls))
            ls.pop(0)
        sums.append(0)
        return sums
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an iterative, `O(n)` solution.

```
def parts_sums(ls):
    sums = [0] * (len(ls) + 1)
    for i, e in enumerate(reversed(ls)):
        sums[len(ls) - i - 1] += sums[len(ls) - i] + e
    return sums
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def parts_sums(ls):
    if len(ls) == 0: return [0]
    ret = [sum(ls)]
    ret.extend(parts_sums(ls[1:]))
    return ret
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the code fails if the length of the list is greater than 90000-(Max Recursion depth exceded)

Answer (score 0):

```
def fn(ls):
    if len(ls)==0:
        return [0]
    return [sum(ls[i:len(ls)]) for i in range(len(ls))]

###################################
print(1,fn([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]))
print(2,fn([]))
```

output will be like

```
1 [20, 20, 19, 16, 10]
2 [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have to reverse list twice, perhaps it is `2*O(n)`, unless
`res[-1]` does not add up to complexity even more:

```
xs = [0,1,3,6,10]

def summed(xs):
    res = [0]
    for x in reversed(xs):
        res.append(x+res[-1])
    return reversed(res)
```

This should perform better, `O(n)`:

```
def summed2(xs):
    res = [0]
    for i, x in enumerate(reversed(xs)):
        res = [x+res[0]] + res
    return res

assert summed2(xs) == [20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]
```